# how to get the cart page without header and footer in prestashop 1.5

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, cart

i am quite new to prestashop, and i want to display the cart page in a fancybox popup, but i don't find a way to call for the cart page without the header and footer.

usually the page for cart i want to display is called with :

```
index.php?controller=order
```

but it is rendered with everything.
no problem with the JS, but how can i get the cart page without header and footer with smarty in my custom theme ?
what controller or template file should i have to create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way to exactly display a page without header and footer, perfect to put it in a popup like fancybox.
you must add a get variable to the URL to display only the content.

*content_only=1*

so for this case of displaying the cart page only, here is the URL

*index.php?controller=order&content_only=1*